# Generate random imagemap coordinates with list of 1000 urls

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Hello So i have transparent picture 995x100px and a list of 1000 urls.
I want to make imagemap with all this urls.
I know how to do it by hand but the problem is i got 1000 urls so i want to generate
1000 random coordinates and put all the urls inside on the fly.

```
      <?php
      $urls = array("www.link1.com", "www.link2.com " ,      "www.link3.com","www.link4.com");
 shuffle($urls); // randomize the urls

    // start the image map
 $map =  <<<EOL
<img src="links.png" width="998" height="100" border="0" usemap="#mymap" />
<map name="mymap">

EOL;

$i = 0;
for ($y = 0; $y = $y + 10; $y < 100) {
for ($x = 0; $x = $x + 10; $x < 995) {
    $bot_x = $x + 9;
    $bot_y = $y + 9;
    $map .= <<<EOL
<area shape="rect" coords="{$x},{$y},{$bot_x},{$bot_y}" href="{$urls[$i]}" />

 EOL;
    $i++;
 }
}
 $map .= <<<EOL
 </map>

 EOL;

echo $map;

?>
```

Comment: Each url should be its own little clickable polygon inside the image map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just output one `<area>` per URL and go on for the `$x` step. If `$x` reaches the maximum per line, set `$x` to `0` again and increase `$y`. Continue until you have processed all URLs:

```
$urls = array(/*... 1000 urls ... */);
shuffle($urls); // randomize the urls

// start the image map
echo '<map name="mymap">';

// output all areas
$area = 10;
$width = 940;
$aw = $area-1; // temp
$iw = (int) $width / $area;
foreach($urls as $i => $url)
{
    $x = $area * ($i % $iw);
    $y = $area * (int) ($i / $iw);
    printf('<area shape="rect" coords="%d,%d,%d,%d" href="%s" />', $x, $y, $x+$aw, $y+$aw, $urlPrefix.$url);
}
// end the image map
echo '</map>';
```

This should not run in you into a memory problem as there is no endless loop and it's directly echo'ing out to the browser which helps as well to not run into the memory limit.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jxfvA4)

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = array(....);
shuffle($urls); // randomize the urls

// start the image map
$map =  <<<EOL
<map name="mymap">

EOL;

$i = 0;
for ($y = 0; $y = $y + 10; $y < 100) {
    for ($x = 0; $x = $x + 10; $x < 995) {
        $bot_x = $x + 9;
        $bot_y = $y + 9;
        $map .= <<<EOL
    <area shape="rect" coords="{$x},{$y},{$bot_x},{$bot_y}" href="{$urls[$i]}" />

EOL;
        $i++;
    }
}
$map .= <<<EOL
</map>

EOL;

echo $map;
```

Comment: can you correct the code i receive error 500 i think i made wrong things                                                                        $urls = array("www.link1.com", 
          "www.link2.com " ,
          "www.link3.com" ,
          "www.link4.com");

Comment: Look at your server's logs to see what the reason for the 500 is.

Comment: i put .php5 extension to see what's happen and i receive this error Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 30408704)